# enable usb debugging on nook color? could not find menu->setting->application_>

Tags: debugging, colors, usb, nook

I could  not find out how to make usb debugging enabled on nook color configuration.  I could not find menu->setting->application to enable the usb debugging.  What is wrong with my device.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to enable USB Debugging on Nook Color (version 1.4.3) - it appears enabled by default, You will have to update your drivers as per this guide: http://nookdevs.com/NookColor_USB_ADB#Windows_XP.2C_Vista_and_7

Once the Nook is connected, and your driver updated, then you can run adb kill-server then adb devices

Answer (score 0):

Unless your NC is rooted, you won't have access to usb debugging.  Sorry.

Comment: Yes. I found out in order to root the nook color, I have to apply provisioning file from B&N. After I put provisioning file on my nook color, I rooted the device.